# VueJS complex v-if

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I want to show a button ONLY if two conditions are met. First I try v-if with only one condition at a time:

```
v-if="editMode"
v-if="$can('customersdelete')"
```

using only one condition at a time, the button is display, so i think both conditions are true. If i use:

```
v-if="editMode && $can('customersdelete')"
```

The button isn't display. $can is a mixin, to validate user has permission to do something.

```
<script>
  export default {
    methods: {
      $can(permissionName) {
        return Permissions.indexOf(permissionName) !== -1;
      },
    },
  };
</script>
```

I don't know why this is not working...

Comment: I really suggest not using mixins and taking advantage of vuex instead

Comment: @DerekPollard I'm new in vuejs, this was the only way I find to do it. I will look into vuex

Comment: Mixins add a lot of magic complexity that can potentially cause issues down the road

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, any subsequent `v-if` is ignored and only the first one is taken into account, as demonstrated by the following example:

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

const Permissions = ['customersdelete'];
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return { editMode: true };
  },
   methods: {
    $can(permissionName) {
      return Permissions.indexOf(permissionName) !== -1;
    },
  },
})
```

```css
code {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  padding: 2px 5px;
  color: red;
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: inline-block;
}
div {
  margin-top: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <label><input type="checkbox" v-model="editMode">editMode</label><br><br>
  
  <div>$can('customersdelete') => <code v-text="$can('customersdelete')"></code></div>
  <div>editMode => <code v-text="editMode"></code></div>
  <hr />
  <div v-if="$can('customersdelete')">
    <code>v-if="$can('customersdelete')"</code>
  </div>
  <div v-if="editMode">
    <code v-if="editMode">v-if="editMode"</code>
  </div>
  <div v-if="editMode && $can('customersdelete')">
    <code>v-if="editMode && $can('customersdelete')"</code>
  </div>
  <div v-if="editMode"
       v-if="$can('customersdelete')">
    <code>v-if="editMode" v-if="$can('customersdelete')"</code>
  </div>
  <div v-if="$can('customersdelete')"
       v-if="editMode">
    <code>v-if="$can('customersdelete')" v-if="editMode"</code>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What I tried to say is that if I use only one condition at a time, the button is displayed. If I use the two conditions at the same time separated by "&&" the button is not shown.

For some reason, when I use the condition separately, they are taken as true. When I use the two conditions within v-if, it takes a condition as false.

Comment: Could you provide a [mcve] demonstrating the issue?

Comment: The problem where my cookies. I deleted and all started to work.

Comment: Turns out I was wrong. Vue only considers the first `v-if` and completely ignores subsequent ones. I added a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest use function and then use in v-if.

example

```
v-if="isButtonShow()"
```

and below is the method portion:

```
methods:{
isButtonShow(){
  if(this.editMode){
    if(this.$can('customersdelete'){
      return true;
    }
  }
 return false;
 }
}
```